# cannot pass JSON into an RSpec test function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I am trying to write test code for a login function, but the test code gives me an error. My rails code is just an API and sends and receives JSON:

```
     NoMethodError:
         undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the `Rspec` code I am trying to write:

```
describe 'POST doctors/login' do
    it 'successfully logs a doctor in' do
      login_params = {
          "login"=>{
              "email" => "knkjn@aol.com",
              "password" => "123456"
          }
      }.to_json

      request_headers ={
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Content_type' => 'application/json'
      }

      post 'login', login_params, request_headers
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
end
```

Below is the method from my controller that I am trying to make a test code for:

```
  def login
      response = Response.new
      this_doctor = Doctor.find_by_username(login_params["username"])
      if this_doctor && this_doctor.authenticate(login_params["password"])
          response.data = {:remember_token => this_doctor.sign_in}
          response.code = true
      else
          response.code = false
          response.error = "Invalid Login"
      end
      render :json => response.json
  end
```

Below is how I accept the JSON request from the params

```
def login_params
    return nil unless params["login"]
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :password)

end
```

here is the `JSON` request (I've tested the JSON request using DHC Chrome plugin for POST requests, and I have verified that the login function in my controller works.):

```
{
    "login": {
        "email": "walasif@gmail.com",
        "password": "123456"
    }
}
```

Is there anything special I have to do to write test code for an API in JSON? The the test code doesn't seem to be sending the params to my controller correctly.

Comment: Looks like a bug in rails, see this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13135)